# Need type="text" input fields to display previously-POST'd entries if errors occur

Tags: php

I've probably not explained what I"m trying to do in the title very well, so here goes:

I've got a HTML entry form, in a `.php` file.  That entry form when submitted files a `POST` operation.  That POST operation has code to check field input, similar to this:

```
    <?php

    ...

    if ($_POST["submitted"] == 1) {  
        //"submitted" is a hidden field with value '1' in the form 

        $isvalid = 1; // Inits to 1, changes to 0 if something fails checks.

        $field1 = $_POST["field1"];
        $field2 = $_POST["field2"];

    ...

    /*
      Checks for validation on each field go here,
      but are not relevant to this question here.
    */

    }

    if ($isvalid == 1) {
        // Send email
    } else { ?>
        <!-- Print form, and error msg. -->

    ...

    <input name="field1" type="text" id="field1" size="32" class="stylingclass">

    ...
```

So the above is example code, but here's the real question:  How can I get any of the text input fields in my form, when submitted and an error occurred, to automatically contain the previous values that were entered, so that the user can correct the entries accordingly, based on whatever constraints I've set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the value parameter using a basic ternary operator:

```
<input name="field1" type="text" id="field1" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["field1"]) ? $_POST["field1"] : ''; ?>" size="32" class="stylingclass">
```

Note that the ternary operator is used here to prevent an error if there is no index of the specified field in the $_POST array

Comment: Can i utilize the variables I've already set earlier in the code (when `$submitted == 1`)?  such that `$field1` would have already received the input from `$_POST` immediately after submission.

Comment: Yes of course, but you should define the variables before the post evaluation. Then you don't need the ternary

Comment: In the code example I gave above, that pretty much matches the code in my form top-to-bottom while removing field names for the form and adding in substitute names/data, while omitting oodles of excess unrelated cruft that already works.  Given that at the beginning of everything, I first check to see if the form's been submitted (see where I check that in the if), and if it has been, i get data from `$_POST` into variables.  is that sufficient?  Or should I just use  your suggestion and use the ternary regardless?  (typing `$_POST` into the code a thousand times is evil though :/)

Comment: No, I would define the expected variables first, before the if ($_POST["submitted"] == 1) line. Then in the post evaluation, you reassign the values of those fields. The ternary thing can be clutterful and unnecessary if you do it this way. I only suggested it in my answer because you defined the variables in the post eval.

Comment: \**looks at actual code**  \**facepalms** i should have init that variable before the if... my bad!  :P   And after shifting that around, it all works!  :)   Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `value="<?=$_POST['field1']?>"` (assuming PHP 5.4, use `<?php echo $_POST['field1'] ?>` otherwise)